# Angular 2 local variable undefined in subscribe() method

Tags: angular

I have a very simple test component which looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "test-component",
    template: "<div>Test</div>",
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    private test : number = 0;
    private service : ClientsService;

    constructor(s : ClientsService) {
        this.service = s;
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.service.loadAllClients().subscribe(d => {
            this.test = 1;
        });
        let comp = this;
    }
}
```

The client service returns an Observable but my question is about the 'test' variable. After the component loads, the first and the first breakpoint is hit, the value of 'test' is 0
[image]
 However, when the breakpoint inside the 'subscribe()' is hit, the 'test' becomes undefined. Any assignments done inside the lambda do not take effect.
[image]

What am I missing here to do proper assignment inside the 'subscribe()'?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything. I think the actual JavaScript code obtained by transpiling the TypeScript uses another variable than `this` to refer to the component inside the callback. Print the value in the console, and see if it's printed properly.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility (I'm not certain) is that `this` is scoping to the service, because you have an instance of it declared in your component.  I haven't done that myself, so I'm not sure.  You could try this to see if it works:

```
@Component({
    selector: "test-component",
    template: "<div>Test</div>",
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    private test : number = 0;

    constructor(private _service : ClientsService) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this._service.loadAllClients().subscribe(d => {
            this.test = 1;
        });
        let comp = this;
    }
}
```

Other than that, nothing looks wrong to me.  I've used the above method many times, and that has preserved `this` for the component scope correctly.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. Turned out the assignment is working correctly but there is something funny going on with the way Webstorm, the IDE we are using, is debugging the code

Comment: More people need to know this answer. I wasted one whole working day trying to figure this out.